# SVN issue: How long time the commit takes until changes are been taken

Tags: svn

I am working on some web application and I use SVN to commit the local code changes to the server. I have commited some code but don't noticed any changes. How long time it takes until the changes are been taken?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is caused by your local time is different by SVN server time.
You could check the time between your computer and server. 
If there is difference, try to sync the time.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How to check this? svn is new for me.

Comment: just look your system time on local computer and server. If you are using windows, look at right-bottom corner.